# ptmalloc, tcmalloc, dmalloc, HOARD, or nedmalloc? (on iOS and Android game)

Tags: ios, ipad, android-ndk, new-operator, tcmalloc

I have a game that is a bit of a memory hog on the iPad from many small allocations. I have a custom game engine written in C++. Has anyone here successfully compiled one of these other allocators on iOS? Were there any gotchas? I'll let people know how my attempt goes.

Comment: any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Android, but nedmalloc works on iOS devices.